# Curiosity - Why would Django REST Framework documentation be made with RoR?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, django-rest-framework

Using the DRF documentation I noticed that wappalizer (https://www.wappalyzer.com/) is identifing the use of Ruby on Rails on the DRF documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org). This looks quite ironic not to use Django.
Does any one know why this would be the case or if it's something related to a wappalyzer missidentification?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's hosted through GitHub pages and Github is built on top of Ruby on Rails.

Comment: What he said. DNS indicates:  CNAME  www.django-rest-framework.org  tomchristie.github.io